# How to configure custom servlet in magnolia CMS

Tags: magnolia

```
I am trying to do registration example in magnolia. I have a registration form, on submission of form control should be transferred to my own written servlet.

snippet for form :

   <body>
        <form action="./register" method="post">
            Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br />
             Email Id:<input type="text" name="email"><br/>
             <input type="submit"   value="Register">
        </form>
    </body>
```

Registration servlet class:

```
public class Registration extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("This is registration servlet");
    }

}
```

I have configured module descriptor :

```
<servlets>
  <servlet>
    <name>RegistrationServlet</name>
    <class>com.rbt.registration.Registration</class>
    <comment>registration servlet</comment>
    <mappings>
      <mapping>/register</mapping>
    </mappings>
  </servlet>
</servlets>
```

and I have also configured template definition.
But when I click on submit button. It shows error that resource not found.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

In your template, when writing html for the form you can also use `action="${ctx.contextPath}/register"` to have form response directed to uri on which servlet is listening.
Also please go to `config:/server/filters/servlets/` and verify that `RegistrationServlet` is correctly add there.
Same problem (although for different servlet) was also discussed at [Magnolia Forum](http://forum.magnolia-cms.com/forum/thread.html?threadId=ea59ba61-5c53-4b6f-b50b-749c4aaf684a&page=1)

HTH, Jan

Answer (score 0):

The mapping you configured in the module descriptor will be relative to your context path. E.g. if your base url is `http://example.com:8080/public` ('public' being your context path), then your servlet will responding to `http://example.com:8080/public/register`.

Check if that url matches the url your form is submitting to. The **`action="./register"`** is a relative path and will depend on the path of the page that contains the form.